# Отправка файла через форму

Tags: php, fileupload, upload

Есть форма 1.html

```
<form action="1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <input type="text" size="40" name="nameFromUser" >
      <input type="file" name="filename"><br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить"><br>
      </form>
```

И файл 1.php с кодом отправки файла на сервер

```
<?php
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
   {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "img/" . $_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
   } else {
      echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
   }
?>
```

Как сделать чтобы файл, который отправляем через форму получил такое название, которое пользователь введёт в текстовое поле?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "img/" . $_POST["nameFromUser"]);` ну и расширение файла обработайте, если его нет в поле имени.

Comment: я уже так делал. Проблема в том что оно добавит файл с именем, который ввёл в текстовое поле, но этот файл изменится. Например присоединяю файл изображения, и после выполнении скрипта в папке вижу видоизменённый файл, но с названием, которое ввёл в текстовом поле.

Comment: собственно в этом и вопрос, как его обработать?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, хтмл:

```
<form action="t.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="text" size="40" name="nameFromUser" >
    <input type="file" name="filename"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"><br>
</form>
```

Пхпэшка, прегматч конечно желательно проверить на false:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
{

    if (isset($_POST['nameFromUser']) && !empty($_POST['nameFromUser'])) {
        preg_match('/\.(.+)/isu', $_FILES['filename']['name'], $matches);
        $extension = $matches[1];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], $_POST['nameFromUser'] . '.' . $extension);
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["filename"]['name']);
    }


} else {
    echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
}
```

Comment: ого. Через регулярные выражения..А точно нет легче пути?

Comment: @Sven ну почему же, можно и через mime тип $_FILES['userfile']['type'] http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Я посмотерел ссылочку. Но всё равно не пойму как сделать. Впихнуть в $_FILES['userfile']['type'] нужный код или надо всё равно проверки делать дополнительно?

Comment: вот что же вместо "png" записать с логикой любого расширения файла и без использования регулярных выражений? move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "gallery/" . $_POST["fileName"] . "." . "png");